# Route is not working, it responds with "404 NOT FOUND"

Tags: laravel

I have a route which has two parameters.

```
Route::delete('/org/{org-id}/delete/user/{user-id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\OrganizationController@deleteUserFromOrg')
->name('delete-user-from-org');
```

i call it in view

```
 <td><a href="{{route('delete-user-from-org', ['org-id'=>$data->id, 'user-id' => $el->id ])}}"><button class="btn btn-danger">Удалить</button></a></td>
```

i think this should work because it substitutes the data correctly and redirects to the page http://localhost:8000/org/11/delete/user/2. REturn 404 error.

It's does not see the controller, I tried some function in the route itself, this does not work either.

Comment: It seems that there might be an issue with the controller specified in the route. Make sure that the controller exists, is located in the correct namespace, and that the method specified in the route (deleteUserFromOrg) exists within the controller. Also, check that the controller is properly imported or included in your routes file.

Also, it's important to make sure that the parameters passed to the route match the parameter name and type defined in the controller method. If the parameter names or types don't match, it will result in a 404 error.

Comment: It's also possible that your server is not running or there might be a problem with the configuration of your application. Try to check the error logs or run your application with debugging mode on if available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Route::delete('/org/{org-id}/delete/user/{user-id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\OrganizationController@deleteUserFromOrg')
->name('delete-user-from-org');
```

look at the `Route::delete()` part. In order to invoke that route  i.e. `delete-user-from-org`, you will require a **DELETE** *request* method (or create a form with a hidden input via `@method('delete')`

When you create a link with <a></a>, the request will be a **GET** (by default unless manipulated by js) which is why you are getting a **404 Not Found** Error. You have two solutions.

### First Solution (via form):

```html
<form action="{{route('delete-user-from-org',['org-id'=>$data->id, 'user-id' => $el->id ])}}" method="POST">
    @method('DELETE')
 
    ...
</form>
```

### Second solution (via ajax):

```
fetch("{{route('delete-user-from-org',['org-id'=>$data->id, 'user-id' => $el->id ])}}", {
  method: 'DELETE',
})
.then(res => res.text()) // or res.json()
.then(res => console.log(res))
```

### Third Solution (change the method): Not recommended. Avoid it.

```
Route::get('/org/{org-id}/delete/user/{user-id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\OrganizationController@deleteUserFromOrg')
->name('delete-user-from-org');
```

from **Route::delete()** to **Route::get()**

Answer (score 1):

Route params should consist of alphabetic characters or _

Please fix your route params name
For example:

```
Route::delete('/org/{org_id}/delete/user/{user_id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\OrganizationController@deleteUserFromOrg')
->name('delete-user-from-org');
```

And your view blade

```
 <td><a href="{{route('delete-user-from-org', ['org_id'=>$data->id, 'user_id' => $el->id ])}}"><button class="btn btn-danger">Удалить</button></a></td>
```